# How to edit angular materials filterPredicate the right way?

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, angular-material

As I couldn't find many examples on the internet that explain how to overwrite the filterPredicate the right way, I decided to ask here. I have a table full of phonenumbers with different states, as you can see in the photo.

[image]

The filtering works, but there is a little bug I dont know how to fix. When I filter for "ASSIGNED", the results for "UNASSIGNED" and "ASSIGNED" will be shown to me. "UNASSIGNED" because it contains "ASSIGNED".

So I figured out I need to overwrite the filterPredicate. I tried it several times but don't quite understand the syntax in it. Can you help me what I need to do?

Thats the html (only necessary part):

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="telefonnummer">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Telefonnummer </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.areaCode.prefix}}-{{element.areaCode.base}}- 
   {{element.extension}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.phoneNumberType}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

Thats my ts class (only necessary parts):

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['telefonnummer', 'status'];

products = [];

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.products);

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.getAllNumbers();
}

@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: any, filter: string) => {
      let matchFound = false;
      if (data === filter) {
          matchFound = true;
      }
  return matchFound;
};
}
```

Thanks for every help!

Comment: I am assuming your data param in filterPredicate  will be an object so you'd need to check a property on that object. (e.g. data.telefonnummer === filter)

Comment: can you also post the code for filter dropdown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering by strings `assigned` and `unassigned` feels wrong on this case. If your table will get more columns and user will be able to set value of either *assigned* or *unassigned*, your sensitive filtering will go wring.

But if thats not an issue (table has two columns and one is for numbers only), here is how you can filter it (though I do not see your DataSource, I assume by the column definition, that `status` is a right key to check for):

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter): boolean => {
  const transformedFilter = filter.trim().toLowerCase();
  if (data.status.trim().toLowerCase() === transformedFilter) {
    return true;
  } else if (data.telefonnummer.trim().toLowerCase() === transformedFilter) {
    return true;
  };
  return false;
}
```

Simple snippet so it makes clear what happens.

p.s. `telefonnummer.trim()` might error if `telefonnummer` is a number, not string. `status.trim()` is also worth checking if its not a falsy value